# Getting warning in Visual Studio 2015 when add Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS with: Targets a different processor than the application

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2015, dts

I'm getting these warning when I try to start the debugging. I built an Windows Form application where execute the dtsx.

When I run the dtsx in the local machine the result is SUCCESS but when I run the Windows Form Application the result is Failure.

My system is:

1. Processor: Intel Core I5 3210M CPU @ 2.50Ghz
2. Memory: 8GB
3. OS: Windows 10 x64

I tried many ways to fix it:

1. Add different versions of Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS in the
      References section any without luck.
2. Add in App.config the line: startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"
3. Add and Reinstall SQL 2014 Client Tool SDK features.
4. Add more Features to Visual Studio 2015.
5. Platform target to: Any CPU, x86 and x64 any without luck.
6. I used this link as reference and many others so I did a lot of research: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx
7. SSIS - Visual Studio 2013 Premium

Warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Line    Suppression State
Warning     Referenced assembly 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.Msxml6_interop\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Msxml6_interop.dll' targets a different processor than the application. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    3505    
Warning     Referenced assembly '\\tsclient\C\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll' targets a different processor than the application. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   3505    
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1819
```

frmSSIS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace alerts_operations
{
    public partial class frmSSIS : Form
    {
        public frmSSIS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnFTP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application myApplication = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

            //Package myPackage = myApplication.LoadPackage(@"C:\ftp_extract.dtsx", null);
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package myPackage = myApplication.LoadPackage(@"V:\ftp_extract.dtsx",null);

            lblStatus.Text = "Executing package...";

            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult myResult = myPackage.Execute();

            // Show the execution result

            lblStatus.Text = "Package result: " + myResult.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Build Log:

```
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'Z:\ACOLON\Projects\operations\operations\bin\Debug\operations.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x2348 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1c24 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'Z:\ACOLON\Projects\operations\operations\bin\Debug\operations.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.Msxml6_interop\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Msxml6_interop.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsMsg\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsMsg.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ExecProcTask\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ExecProcTask.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'ST_9d880699f696403b9ab1169dab706d45'. Module was built without symbols.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration.Install\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.Install.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.WSMan.Management\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.WSMan.Management.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Management.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x7e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'operations.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: operations.vshost.exe): Loaded 'ST_c01711d8321445bcbe1c4f5abc4dee25'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x246c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x54 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1df0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7748] operations.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any other alternative, options or suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this type of error crop up on me a few different times in ASP.NET applications. A combination of changing the Build settings back to any CPU (which it looks like you already did) for all of the projects associated with the application, and manually deleting the /bin and /obj folders in all of the project directories usually worked. I also made sure to close visual studio before deleting those folders.

Comment: I deleted it but still same issue.